# Issues with system test setup using Capybara and Selenium on Rails 5.1 app (upgraded from Rails 4)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, testing, rspec, capybara

I'm attempting to set up system tests with Capybara and Selenium on an existing Rails 5.1 (Upgraded from Rails 4) app that already had capybara based feature tests. Here's what I've done so far.

In the gem file under `group :development, :test`:

```
gem 'chromedriver-helper'  
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'rack_session_access'
```

In the `environments/development.rb` and `environments/test.rb`:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
```

In the `spec\rails_helper.rb`:

```
Capybara.register_driver :selenium do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

Capybara.configure do |config|
  config.default_max_wait_time = 10 # seconds
  config.default_driver = :selenium
  config.app_host = 'http://localhost:3000'
  config.server_host = 'localhost'
end
```

The issues I'm having are both with new systems tests and old feature tests.

With the system tests it appears that Capybara isn't creating a page object as I get `undefined local variable or method 'page'` Additionally when I duplicate the same test under the feature test directory I don't have this issue.

With the old Capybara feature tests, working with the rackTest driver, a Chrome window opens but I get `No route matches [GET] "/rack_session/edit"`

`config.middleware.use RackSessionAccess::Middleware` is already present in the `environments/test.rb`

Example system test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe User do
  let(:user) { create :user }
  let(:membership) { create :membership, admin: true}
  let(:admin) { create :user, memberships: [membership] }

  context 'viewing the index' do
    it 'directs you to the appropriate page' do
      set_current_user(admin)
      visit root_url
      click_button 'Manage Users'
      expect(page.current_url).to end_with users_path
      expect(page).to have_selector 'h1', text: 'Users'
    end
  end
end
```

Example feature test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe 'edit an assignment' do
  let(:roster) { create :roster }
  let(:user) { create :user, rosters: [roster] }
  before :each do
    Timecop.freeze Date.new(2018, 1, 10)
    set_current_user(user)
  end
  after :each do
    Timecop.return
  end

  context 'returns the user to the appropriate index page' do
    let(:date_today) { Date.new(2017, 4, 4) }
    let(:start_date) { Date.new(2017, 3, 31) }
    let(:month_date) { date_today.beginning_of_month }
    it 'redirects to the correct URL' do
      visit roster_assignments_url(roster, date: date_today)
      visit new_roster_assignment_url(roster, date: start_date)
      click_button 'Create'
      expect(current_url)
        .to eq roster_assignments_url(roster,
                                      date: month_date)
    end
```

In the `spec_helper`:

```
def set_current_user(user)
  page.set_rack_session user_id: user.id
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the gem `puma` installed. New rails 5 projects have it installed by default, but your app was made in Rails 4, which is why it didn't.

Why is this? Well, if you were to do a bundle update (and I'll admit I can't explain why) you'd get this error when trying to run the specs, which is a lot more explanatory:

`` System test integration requires Rails >= 5.1 and has a hard dependency on a webserver and `capybara`, please add capybara to your Gemfile and configure a webserver (e.g. `Capybara.server = :webrick`) before attempting to use system tests. ``

Googling this error led me to [this page](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/issues/1930), which explains Capybara needs a server.
After adding puma, I'm able to run system tests on your application.

Comment: I have puma in my gemfile and `Capybara.server = :puma` & I'm seeing this error.

Comment: I don't believe setting the Capybara server to puma manually is necessary as it's the default. How are you requiring Capybara in your spec/rails helper?

Answer (score 0):

A number of issues here.

1. Why are you setting - config.app_host = 'http://localhost:3000' ??? That would run the tests against your dev instance rather than the test instance Capybara starts.  `app_host` really should only ever need to be set if you are doing subdomain based testing.  This could be the reason for the `no route` error (normally `rack_session_access` would only be included in the test environment), or that could be caused by having not actually included the middleware as specified in the `rack_session_access` gem readme.
2. NEVER do expectations against `current_path`/`current_url` directly, instead use the provided matchers or you'll have flaky tests

   expect(page).to have_current_path(users_path)
3. `page` is just an alias for `Capybara.current_session` and is a member of the module Capybara::DSL. If it's not available in the scope of your tests that it most likely means Capybara::DSL isn't included.  That would normally be done by `rspec-rails` - https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails/blob/master/lib/rspec/rails/vendor/capybara.rb#L21 - so it's possible you haven't actually set the test type to 'system'. If it's that it's not available in your spec_helper methods, just using `Capybara.current_session` instead is usually easier.

Comment: 1. I have to say setting `config.app_host  =  'http://localhost:3000'` was a  bit of a band aid solution I read somewhere. However the test instance Capybara starts seems to not be working how it should. The browser will cycle through three pages consisting of Example Domain @ example.com, Update rack session, and Rack session data @ localhost.  

2. I'll look into it.  

3. This resolves my page issue but, I now get `undefined local variable or method 'root_url'` for my links.

Comment: @Voxorin - I don't understand what you mean by "The browser will cycle through three pages ..." - The browser won't do anything unless your test or the page is telling it to do something.  Try visiting `xxx_path` rather than `xxx_url` and see if that changes things for you.

Comment: Right, something in my setup is wrong here. Selenium opens a browser and Capybara creates a page that looks like a core example to me. Then while the test attempts to run a rack session update page with an input box followed by a rack session data page is displayed. Could this also have to do with Capybara::DSL

Comment: @Voxorin No, it would only be a Capybara::DSL issue if you were getting no method errors.  I'm guessing the rack_session pages are when you call `set_rack_session` (via set_current_user), although I'm not 100% sure on that because I don't use that gem.   Did you try switching to `xxx_path` instead of `xxx_url` in your `visit` calls??

Comment: As for the `undefined local variable or method 'root_url'` that would be because ``Rails.application.routes.url_helper` isn't included in whatever scope you're attempting to call `root_url` from.